# how to compile and modify android 4.0.3 source code in eclipse using windows

Tags: android, android-source, android-ndk

I have downloaded the android source code 4.0.3, installed cygwin with make and gcc, and downloaded
ndk and sdk, integrated eclipse with cdt and adt. Using windows 7 64bit.

Can you guys tell me how to build this source code in eclipse in order to customize the native settings
menu.

Thanks in advance.

FYI :I have been through google, stackoverflow, but couldn't find any lead which works.

Answer (score 0):

See these pages in the Developer docs: [Initializing a Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). This page seems to indicate that Mac, and Linux are the only supported build environment OS. I would suggest using one of those instead of Windows 7.

Once you've got environment set up see also: [Building and Running](http://source.android.com/source/building.html)

Comment: :Thanks Tim, but I have managed to have that linux environment with cygwin and downloaded the source code using git. I need to compile and build 4.0.3 source code to modify native settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be *very* difficult. From my experience, even on the supported platforms there  are difficulties to tune build environment. Windows is not supported so I think this is almost impossible there.

Maybe in your case it's worth to install a virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks Yury, I tried this even with virtual box having ubuntu 12 in that. But it didn't work.

Comment: Current development environment is based on the ubuntu 10.04. I use this system for the development. Try to use 10.04 in your VM.